# RegEx match with whitespace but exclude in Output

Tags: asp.net, regex, replace, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to **match multiple lines** in source code between starting and ending markers (`<%` and `%>`), but I need the output variable (if that's what it is called) to **exclude any surrounding newlines** at the *end* of the matched code block. Because I am doing replace, I still need to be replacing all the way through the ending marker (`%>`), regardless of whether there are newlines before that marker.

Simplified example:

```
<%
    SomeCode1
    SomeCode2

    SomeCode3
    SomeCode4

%>
```

The goal is to output using `$x` the code lines between (and including) `SomeCode1` and `SomeCode4` while **retaining the newlines between 2 and 3** but **excluding any newline(s) after 4**.

Thus far what I have come up with (simplified here) is to replace `<%([ \t\r\n]*)([^%]*)%>` with `x$2y`. The actual situation is more complex, but this serves to show the basic problem, which is that the result contains any extra newlines between `SomeCode4` and `%>`. **How do you replace the whole deal while excluding the trailing newlines?**

**Update 1:** The real goal is to combine adjacent inline ASPX VB.NET code blocks in a clean way that tabs well. Example input:

```
<% SomeCode()
   SomeCode2()
%>
<%
   SomeCode3()
   SomeCode4()
%>
```

The result of the following replace seems to work pretty well for combining without extraneous newlines within, although it still may contain some extra newlines in the final form:

Replacing:

```
(\r\n)([\s]*)<%(?!=|-)[\s\r]*([^%]*?)[\s\r]*%>[\s\r]*<%(?!=|-)[\s\r]*([^%]*)
```

With:

```
$1$2<%$1$2    $3$1$2    $4$1$2
```

Output of above example with above replace (removes newline after `SomeCode2()` but still has newline at end of result):

```
<%
   SomeCode()
   SomeCode2()
   SomeCode3()
   SomeCode4()

%>
```

For those wondering, the reason a simple replace of `%>[\s\r]*<%` is not viable is because it would potentially include comments (`<%--abc--%>`) and the other inline code expressions (`<%=abc%>`), both of which need to be excluded from the replace operation.

**Update 2 (seems good):** With the help of Wiktor Stribiżew in the answers and comments, I was able to find something that is short and seems to work desirably in both Visual Studio 2017 and in the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gXT8gF/7):

Replacing:

```
(\r?\n)([ \t]*)<%(?!=|-)[\s]*([^%]*?)[\s]*%>[\s]*<%(?!=|-)[\s]*([^%]*?)[\s]*(%>)
```

With:

```
$1$2<%$1$2    $3$1$2    $4$1$2$5
```

Be sure to see Wiktor's demos in the comments for alternative syntax.

Comment: Try `<%([\s\r]*)([^%]*?)[\s\r]*%>`

Comment: Please post a comprehensive sample input with exact expected output

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, On a second try, it appears your suggestion may be the answer. At first I missed the `?`. What is the function of the `?` in the middle part?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I have updated my question to include a more detailed example input and my full replace expression thus far. It works pretty well, but there are still newlines at the very end. This is not that big of a deal, but still is suboptimal. I tried using `([^%]*?)[\s\r]*` at the end instead of `([^%]*)`, but it seemed to break the first "lazy quantifier" as you called it.

Comment: You should be a bit more careful with the replacement, see [an updated demo](https://regex101.com/r/gXT8gF/1) with a bit different replacement string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I looked at the demo, but it still has the same issue. Also, for the start of the matching, I actually want it to match only one newline, hence the simple `(\r\n)`. In the demo, if you put more newlines at the very top (above the `<%`), it propagates those newlines throughout the result. For the result, the goal is to have the `%>` always on its own line immediately below the last code line. The last code line (`SomeCode4()`) may have zero or more newlines and other whitespace, but this is to be excluded from the result, and `%>` should always be on its own line.

Comment: In other words, each block of code is being trimmed of unpredictable whitespace at the beginning and end.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/gXT8gF/3.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, See [https://regex101.com/r/gXT8gF/4](https://regex101.com/r/gXT8gF/4). The goal is to remove the extra newlines after `SomeCode4()`.

Comment: Ok, I see, check https://regex101.com/r/gXT8gF/6

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Thanks. That got me on the right track to finding something that works correctly for me in Visual Studio 2017 while also working correctly on the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gXT8gF/7). I made some changes to keep it short and allow for input that is tabbed over. I am not worried about whitespace that appears before `<%`, as long as it does not end up inside with the actual code. At this point I am satisfied with the result. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
<%([\s\r]*)([^%]*?)[\s\r]*%>
```

**Details**

- `<%` - a literal substring
- `([\s\r]*)` - Group 1 (may be referred to with `$1` from the replacement pattern): any 0+ whitespaces (in VS S&R, the `\s` does not match `\r`)
- `([^%]*?)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than `%`, as few as possible (as `*?` is a lazy quantifier and the subsequent patterns are tried first, and only if they fail to match, this pattern is "expanded")
- `[\s\r]*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `%>` - a literal substring.